# Error: Class A is not a base of Class B C++

Tags: c++

When I try to call the function in line **
through this function:

```
template<class T,int SIZE>
T const& Array<T,SIZE>::const_iterator::operator*() const {
    return this->Array<T,SIZE>::iterator::operator*();
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
error: 'Array<int, 3>::iterator' is not a base of 'const Array<int, 3>::const_iterator'
```

Can anyone explain why?

```
 template <class T, int SIZE>
    class Array {
        T data[SIZE];
    public:
        explicit Array();
        Array(const Array& a); //copy constructor
        ~Array(); //destructor
        class iterator  {
            Array<T,SIZE>* array;
            int index;
        public:
            iterator(Array<T,SIZE>* array,int index);
            T& operator*() const; //**
        };
class const_iterator {
        const Array<T,SIZE>* array;
        int index;

    public:
        T const& operator*() const;
};

    }
```

Comment: The reason why is because 'Array<int, 3>::iterator' is not a base of 'const Array<int, 3>::const_iterator', exactly as the error message says. Your `const_iterator` is not derived from your `iterator`, so your attempt to access it, as if it were a base class, is not going to work. Pretty straightforward.